# How to break text line on a WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE "Edit" text field on Win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm showing text on a:

`hWndText = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        "Edit", cquestions.at(1).c_str(),  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
        10, //x
        10, //y
        TextFieldWidth, //width
        100, //height
        hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

(`cquestions` is a `std::vector<std::string>`). Although the result is shown below.

[image]

I've tried inserting `"\n"` to it but it won't work.

How can I make it so the text will wrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `ES_MULTILINE` style to make an edit control display more than one line of text.